# Mutate a variable for many rows in a group based on one row R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking to code a new variable for multiple rows in a group based on one row in the group and not finding a working solution.

Minimal working example:

```
df <- data.frame("participant" = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                                   "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2"), 
                 "group" = c("1111", "1111", "1111", "1111", "1113", "1113", "1113", "1114",
                             "1111", "1111", "1113", "1113", "1113", "1113", "1113", "1113"),
                 "item" = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h",
                            "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"),
                 "value" = c("xyz", "hlm", "test", "nop", "test", "nop", "hlm", "test",
                            "hlm", "test", "xyz", "xyz", "test", "xyz", "nop", "xyz"),
                 "type" = c("1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2",
                            "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "1", "1"))
```

I want to 1) group by *participant* and *group*, 2) check the *type* of each *item* which has *value* == "test", then 3) code a new column *test_type* which spreads the *type* of each "test" across all rows within the same *participant*/*group* combination.

The final result should look like this:

```
df$test_type <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2",
                   "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2")
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to subset the 'type' that corresponds to 'test' in `value' column after grouping by  'participant' and 'group'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(participant, group) %>% 
   mutate(test_type = type[value %in% 'test']) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 16 × 6
   participant group item  value type  test_type
   <chr>       <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    
 1 1           1111  a     xyz   1     1        
 2 1           1111  b     hlm   2     1        
 3 1           1111  c     test  1     1        
 4 1           1111  d     nop   2     1        
 5 1           1113  e     test  2     2        
 6 1           1113  f     nop   1     2        
 7 1           1113  g     hlm   1     2        
 8 1           1114  h     test  2     2        
 9 2           1111  i     hlm   1     1        
10 2           1111  j     test  1     1        
11 2           1113  k     xyz   2     2        
12 2           1113  l     xyz   2     2        
13 2           1113  m     test  2     2        
14 2           1113  n     xyz   3     2        
15 2           1113  o     nop   1     2        
16 2           1113  p     xyz   1     2
```

Comment: Sorry, I see my example was a bit misleading. I've edited it now. There aren't just NA's in type, they can be filled as well, but we only care about type when the value=="test". So there's some filtering involved, but filtering like mutate(test_type = type[value=="test"]) throws an error.

Comment: @user9974638 with your updated data, the update in my solution works

Comment: @user9974638 i don't get any error with `type[value == 'test']` or `type[value %in% 'test']` with the example you provided.  As you didn't provide the error message, it is not clear as well

Comment: I assume there are only one 'test' per each group

Comment: Now it works! Thanks! Sorry, had a conflict between dplyr/plyr.

Comment: This result works as long as every participant and group has a "test" row, but how can I get this to insert NAs for participant-group combos which have no "test" row?

Comment: @user9974638 try `%>% mutate(test_type = if(!'test' %in% value) NA_character_ else type[value %in% 'test'])`